# Can I call storyapi from vuex?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, storyblok

I'm using **storyblok-nuxt** module. I plugged it in `nuxt.cofig.js` and it works fine in page when I call it directly in the asyncData method as such:

```
  asyncData({ app }) {
    return app.$storyapi.get("cdn/stories/articles", {
        version: "draft"
      })
```

In order to call it from vuex I'm importing it:

```
import storyapi from 'storyapi'
```

But Nuxt gives me an error:

```
Cannot find module 'storyapi'
```

Can I use this module in vuex, and if yes - what's solution?

Comment: I'd appreciate any comments regarding the quality of my question in order to avoid down voting in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `storyapi` with Nuxt is very easy. In your asyncData you can dispatch your action like:

```
asyncData ({ store }) {
  store.dispatch('loadSettings', {version: "draft"})
}
```

And in your store actions, you can go for `this.$storyapi` directly. There is no need to import anything. Nuxt take cares of everything for you:

```
export const actions = {
  loadSettings({commit}, context) {
    return this.$storyapi.get("cdn/stories/articles", {
      version: context.version
    }).then((res) => {
      // execute your action and set data    
      commit('setSettings', res.data)
    })
  }
}
```

For more info:

- [How to use the nuxt context in an vuex store?](https://www.storyblok.com/faq/how-to-use-the-nuxt-context-in-an-vuex-store)